# How can I initialize an empty binary search tree in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a Binary Search Tree in C as a learning exercise. I have the following struct that represents a node.

```
typedef struct BSTNode {
    int data;
    struct BSTNode *parent;
    struct BSTNode *left;
    struct BSTNode *right;
} BSTNode;

BSTNode* create_BinarySearchTree() {
    BSTNode *p = malloc(sizeof(BSTNode));
    p->left = NULL;
    p->right = NULL;
    p->parent = NULL;
    return p;
}
```

Since I can't set `node->data = NULL;` it defaults to `0` in C. So when I initialize my BST, it has a single node with a value of 0 instead of being empty.

Is there an elegant way to handle this? Do I need a separate struct just to represent the tree itself, as such?

```
typedef struct BinarySearchTree {
    struct BSTNode *root;
} BinarySearchTree;
```

Comment: As an aside, prefer `BSTNode* p = malloc(sizeof *p);`. Also, since C99 compound-literals are a thing, so consider `*p = (BSTNode){0};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need a separate struct just to represent the tree itself, as such?

Yes, and, no.

No, it isn't technically required, you could use `BSTNode t = null;` to indicate an empty tree

But since, as you add & remove nodes to the tree, the root changes, you'd have to

1. have a mechanism to keep the root up to date for at least the immediate caller, and,
2. it will be difficult for another party to keep track of, to have a reference to, the whole tree as the root is changing.

In regards to the first item, the API will have to be something like:

```
BSTNode addNode ( BSTNode root, int data );
BSTNode removeNode ( BSTNode root, int data );
```

where the return value of `addNode` & `removeNode` is the new root (which could be unchanged, or a new root node, or null), which the caller will have to make note of each time such a function that can change the tree is called.

So, the answer is yes, if you want to mitigate these difficulties.  With an intermediating object that represents the tree in its entirety, there's no need for callers to capture the current root, and a third party can reference the whole tree once and for all (without needing updates).

Comment: Note that in a language such as C, having a pointer to the variable that holds the tree root amounts to referencing the whole tree with all tree-manipulation opportunities including exchanging or deleting the root. So if you remember that `BSTNode **` is a pointer to a variable that points to a `BSTNode` (or is `NULL` in case you have an empty tree) everything should be fine. C isn't object oriented, and it's not necessary to have an explicit type representing a data structure.